# Making an association immutable

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In my GORM objects it is possible to mark an association as `updateable false` which means once it is set it can't be changed.  Good.  However, it still possible to change it in memory.  For example, the various GORM APIs, `addToBlah` will still be invoked and `save()` won't throw any error.  This can lead to unpredictable code.  I am just wondering is there any way to stop this? For example, I could override the `addToBlah()` methods, put a check in there?  Just wondering if there is something better?

Comment: why not provide a proper domain layer and use the gorm as what is is: a database abstraction?

Comment: Reminds me of the old joke - a guy goes into a doctor's office and says "Hey doc, it hurts when I do this", so the doctor says "Ok, so don't do that".

Comment: As far as i know there's nothing, you have to override addTo and put a check. but it doesnt look good, if you describe what you are trying to achieve some one may be able to give a better alternative solution